# how to rewrite GET param using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the url:

`https://pieskowato.pl/posts.php?post=param`

to

`https://pieskowato.pl/posts/param`

i found the htaccess config and it works at localhost but not in production..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/post/([^/]*)$ /post.php?post=$1 [L]
```

url https://pieskowato.pl/post/dlaczego-warto-adoptowac-psa

Hosting OVH.com

Comment: @biesior I guess so, i'm using OVH

Comment: Where did you "find" this `.htaccess`? "it works at localhost" - where exactly were you putting these directives at "localhost"? What do you think the first rule is doing? The second rule would never have worked in a `.htaccess` context?

Comment: @MrWhite i just put it in the main directory, the same place where i got index.php file and others.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(post)/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?post=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Still the same, nothing changed.

Comment: @KamilZachradnik, could you please do let me know which URL you are hitting?

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```sh
# important to turn off MultiViews
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# fix css/js/images
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# handle /post/anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ post.php?post=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```